# Multirow table title cannot be horizontally centered

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have written the table shown below, but no matter what options I try, the title of the table is aligned to the right and does not appear in bold font.
What can I do to rectify this?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{l}\textbf{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.} \\
\hline
\textbf{File Line} & \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Example} \\
\hline
Meta line 1 & Parent filename & ``Report generated from input\_filename.FASTQ'' \\
\hline
Meta line 2 & Adapter sequence used & ``Adapter sequence: AGATCG'' \\
\hline
Line 1 & Read ID & ``@HWI-3:1101:1239:1968'' \\
\hline
Line 2 & Read sequence & ``TNGCNTAGNGGATTGCATGCAGA'' \\
\hline
Line 3 & Adapter sequence found & ``Adapter contamination: AGA'' \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You are missing a set of `{}` around the `\textbf` command. The line should be the following: `\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.}}` instead of `\multicolumn{3}{l}\textbf{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.}`.

Comment: Please clarify: In the title of the question you write: "vertically centered". I guess you mean horizontally centered instead? But why would you use `\multicolumn{3}{l}` then, since `l` will left align the contents of the multicolumn command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll>{\RaggedRight}X @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.}} \\
    \midrule
\textbf{File Line} & \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Example} \\
    \midrule
Meta line 1 & Parent filename & ``Report generated from input\_filename.FASTQ'' \\
Meta line 2 & Adapter sequence used & ``Adapter sequence: AGATCG'' \\
Line 1 & Read ID & ``@HWI-3:1101:1239:1968'' \\
Line 2 & Read sequence & ``TNGCNTAGNGGATTGCATGCAGA'' \\
Line 3 & Adapter sequence found & ``Adapter contamination: AGA'' \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
or
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption*{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll>{\RaggedRight}X @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{File Line} & \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Example} \\
    \midrule
Meta line 1 & Parent filename & ``Report generated from input\_filename.FASTQ'' \\
Meta line 2 & Adapter sequence used & ``Adapter sequence: AGATCG'' \\
Line 1 & Read ID & ``@HWI-3:1101:1239:1968'' \\
Line 2 & Read sequence & ``TNGCNTAGNGGATTGCATGCAGA'' \\
Line 3 & Adapter sequence found & ``Adapter contamination: AGA'' \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In connection with @leanderiis comment

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Adapterfinder.py Output File Structure.}} \\ \hline
{\textbf{File Line}}    & {\textbf{Element}}    & {\textbf{Example}} \\ \hline
Meta line 1             & Parent filename       & ``Report generated from input\_filename.FASTQ'' \\ \hline
Meta line 2             & Adapter sequence used & ``Adapter sequence: AGATCG'' \\ \hline
Line 1                  & Read ID               & ``@HWI-3:1101:1239:1968'' \\ \hline
Line 2                  & Read sequence         & ``TNGCNTAGNGGATTGCATGCAGA'' \\ \hline
Line 3                  & Adapter sequence 
                                        found   & ``Adapter contamination: AGA'' \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```